# averaging every five minutes data as one datapoint in pandas dataframe ovewr multiple days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
"16-feb-05 07:10",   6.8,  8.1, 0.0214, 1.8105, 0.0214, 1.6985, 1.00, 2.631
"16-feb-05 07:15",  18.3,  8.1, 0.0214, 1.8093, 0.0214, 1.6977, 1.00, 2.656
"16-feb-05 07:20",  12.7,  8.1, 0.0214, 1.8083, 0.0214, 1.6971, 1.00, 2.673
...
...

"01-mar-05 00:00", -10.1,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3718, 0.0214, 1.6761, 1.00,29.419
"01-mar-05 00:05",   5.1,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3722, 0.0214, 1.6767, 1.00,29.425
"01-mar-05 00:10",  -3.4,  7.9, 0.0214, 1.3728, 0.0214, 1.6774, 1.00,29.421
```

... Then the data turns hourly

```
"02-dec-06 13:00",  -2.8,  7.5, 0.0214, 1.0499, 0.0214, 1.5777, 1.00,46.429
"02-dec-06 14:00",   3.4,  7.5, 0.0214, 1.0488, 0.0214, 1.5767, 1.00,46.482
```

and I would like to to take an average every 5 minutes of the 2nd column only ignoring the rest.

I tried:

```
names=['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation']
px_all=pd.read_csv('Output1.csv',parse_dates=True,index_col=0,names=names)
close_px=px_all[['Conc']] #So was only concerned with the one column 

close_px.resample('5min',how='sum')
```

And then it says 'Conc' is not an index. 
Does anyone have a suggestion, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works nice:

```
#pandas 0.18.0
#df1 = close_px[['Conc']].resample('5min').sum()
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
df1 = close_px[['Conc']].resample('5min',how='sum')
print (df1)
                     Conc
Date                     
2005-02-16 07:10:00   6.8
2005-02-16 07:15:00  18.3
2005-02-16 07:20:00  12.7
2005-02-16 07:25:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:30:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:35:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:40:00   NaN
...
...
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""16-feb-05 07:10,6.8,8.1,0.0214,1.8105,0.0214,1.6985,1.00,2.631
16-feb-05 07:15,18.3,8.1,0.0214,1.8093,0.0214,1.6977,1.00,2.656
16-feb-05 07:20,12.7,8.1,0.0214,1.8083,0.0214,1.6971,1.00,2.673
01-mar-05 00:00,-10.1,7.9,0.0214,1.3718,0.0214,1.6761,1.00,29.419
01-mar-05 00:05,5.1,7.9,0.0214,1.3722,0.0214,1.6767,1.00,29.425
01-mar-05 00:10,-3.4,7.9,0.0214,1.3728,0.0214,1.6774,1.00,29.421
02-dec-06 13:00,-2.8,7.5,0.0214,1.0499,0.0214,1.5777,1.00,46.429
02-dec-06 14:00,3.4,7.5,0.0214,1.0488,0.0214,1.5767,1.00,46.482"""

names=['Date','Conc','Flow','SZ','SB','RZ','RB','Fraction','Attenuation']
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=0, names=names, parse_dates=True)
print (df)
                     Conc  Flow      SZ      SB      RZ      RB  Fraction  \
Date                                                                        
2005-02-16 07:10:00   6.8   8.1  0.0214  1.8105  0.0214  1.6985       1.0   
2005-02-16 07:15:00  18.3   8.1  0.0214  1.8093  0.0214  1.6977       1.0   
2005-02-16 07:20:00  12.7   8.1  0.0214  1.8083  0.0214  1.6971       1.0   
2005-03-01 00:00:00 -10.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3718  0.0214  1.6761       1.0   
2005-03-01 00:05:00   5.1   7.9  0.0214  1.3722  0.0214  1.6767       1.0   
2005-03-01 00:10:00  -3.4   7.9  0.0214  1.3728  0.0214  1.6774       1.0   
2006-12-02 13:00:00  -2.8   7.5  0.0214  1.0499  0.0214  1.5777       1.0   
2006-12-02 14:00:00   3.4   7.5  0.0214  1.0488  0.0214  1.5767       1.0   

                     Attenuation  
Date                              
2005-02-16 07:10:00        2.631  
2005-02-16 07:15:00        2.656  
2005-02-16 07:20:00        2.673  
2005-03-01 00:00:00       29.419  
2005-03-01 00:05:00       29.425  
2005-03-01 00:10:00       29.421  
2006-12-02 13:00:00       46.429  
2006-12-02 14:00:00       46.482  

df1 = df[['Conc']].resample('5min').sum()
print (df1)
                     Conc
Date                     
2005-02-16 07:10:00   6.8
2005-02-16 07:15:00  18.3
2005-02-16 07:20:00  12.7
2005-02-16 07:25:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:30:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:35:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:40:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:45:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:50:00   NaN
2005-02-16 07:55:00   NaN
2005-02-16 08:00:00   NaN
...
```

If need output as serie:

```
df1 = df.resample('5min')['Conc'].sum()
print (df1)
Date
2005-02-16 07:10:00     6.8
2005-02-16 07:15:00    18.3
2005-02-16 07:20:00    12.7
2005-02-16 07:25:00     NaN
2005-02-16 07:30:00     NaN
2005-02-16 07:35:00     NaN
...
...
2006-12-02 13:45:00     NaN
2006-12-02 13:50:00     NaN
2006-12-02 13:55:00     NaN
2006-12-02 14:00:00     3.4
Freq: 5T, Name: Conc, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am not sure what is problem, can you check if this works?

Comment: What was problem? some typo?

Comment: I'm still not sure, so I think it must have been a typo. Regardless thank you

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Btw, I think you can update your pandas version and use `close_px[['Conc']].resample('5min').sum()`.

Comment: I have two CSV files and this worked with one but not the other even through, the one it didnt work for just has more lines

Comment: Found difference, in the CSV fiile where it moans about the index it turns hourly. So it can't take a 10 minute average. From every hour.

Comment: So the CSV file stops working whne switched to hourly at this point, it says 
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Figured this was because, I am after 10 minute averahes and can't do this on the hour: So tried adding 
   df_filled=df.resample('10min').ffill()
At which point it still moaned? 
Any suggestions-sorry

Comment: There is problem you have no datetimindex. What is `print df.index` ?

Comment: If there are dates, you need `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)`. If not, you need set column with dates as index - e.g. `df = df.set_index('dates_col')`

Comment: Turns out that somepoint during the CSV file it changed from a quotation mark at the end to a : and so now I've got rid of this random colon that appeared. So really sorry, think its now working... (he says hopefully)